# How to determine whether a character supported by UIFont?

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

How to determine whether a character supported by UIFont?

For example: how to determine whether a UIFont supports "サポート" or "поддержка"

special thx

Comment: You said UIFont, not CGFont. I was unaware users could share fonts via iTunes - so you would in code ask the system for the list of available fonts, that the shared font shows up? Can you get a CGFont using the same name?

Comment: CGFont is a way of accessing fonts at a lower level of abstraction, and is part of the Core Graphics API , although it is also heavily used in the Core Text API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName: - It returns 0 if the glyph doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks, but in my project it must be done programmatically, because fonts are added by user via iTunes file sharing

Comment: Look at CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName: - It returns 0 if the glyph doesn't exist.